# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ionic

Tags: android, cordova, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I'm developing an application using ionic , I could retrieve data from my webApi server and display them on the navigator with `ionic serve` but when I try to execute it on the emulator:`ionic run android -l -c` i get this error :`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

[image]

What is strange is that the *$scope* contains the required data and I could log them .

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your web api? Also, localhost in the emulator is the emulator machine, not your web api server. You would need to expose your web api server on your network. I did that on Windows 10 by configuring IIS as a reverse proxy that forwards requests to IIS express

Comment: thank you but how can i do that?

Comment: Do what? enabling CORS? Expose your web api server to your network? or configuring IIS as a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 9):

More than likely localhost on the Android device/emulator does not resolve to the IP of your development machine/server.  Localhost probably points to the device/emulator itself.  Can you hit the actual IP Address of your machine instead?  Or can you host the web service somewhere in the cloud and try that?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my time)

Answer (score 7):

From your emulator (and the Ionic app is running in the emulator), `http://localhost` no longer refers to your computer, it refers to the emulated devise. Understanding this, `http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/` is not a valid endpoint in your devise so the request fails.

To solve this you have two options:

First option is to create a simple proxy in your Ionic app. Edit your `ionic.config.json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  ...
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/localhost",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:26309"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when doing a request from your Ionic app, simply write `/localhost/api/User/getAll/` and it should work.

Second option is to use the private IP of your computer as the endpoint domain. So instead of using `http://localhost:26309` you can use `http://192.168.X.Y:26309`

Comment: The private IP of my computer was the way to go. That was a clever solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since the cordova app is loaded from the device file system, it has a different origin than the web api. The app tries to call the web api, but this is prohibited by the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). To overcome this issue you need to [enable CORS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx) on your web api.

To enable CORS you need to install [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors) NuGet package and use [`EnableCors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute. For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using WebApiServer.Models;

namespace WebApiServer.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("databases")]
    [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    public class DatabasesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var databases = new List<DatabaseCategory>()
            {
                new DatabaseCategory
                {
                    CategoryName = "Bases de datos relacionales",
                    Databases = new List<Database>()
                    {
                        new Database() { DatabaseName = "SQL Server" },
                        new Database() { DatabaseName = "Oracle" },
                        new Database { DatabaseName = "PostgreSQL" }
                    }
                },
                new DatabaseCategory
                {
                    CategoryName = "Bases de datos NoSQL",
                    Databases = new List<Database>()
                    {
                        new Database() { DatabaseName = "RavenDB" },
                        new Database { DatabaseName = "CouchBase" },
                        new Database { DatabaseName = "MongoDB" }
                    }
                }
            };
            return Ok(databases);
        }
    }
}
```

If the app running on a device (emulated or physical) calls http://localhost:26309/databases it tries to connect to port 26309 on the device itseft, not to the developer machine that is running the web api. So you receive `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, because no one on the device is listening on that port.

So instead of using `http://localhost:26309` you should be using your developer machine ip address or a DNS name that resolves to it.  For example `http://192.168.8.162:26309` or `http://yourMachine.yourDomain.com:26309`. But then you will hit another problem, your web api is running on the development web server IIS Express which doesn't allow remote connections. It can be configured to allow remote connections, but then you would have to execute Visual Studio as administrator. A better solution is installing IIS and configuring it to behave as reverse proxy. This can be done in Windows 10 Pro by installing [URL rewrite and ARR](http://blogs.iis.net/iisoobs), and [configuring it](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis):

1. First install IIS, go to control panel, Turn Windows Features On or
   Off, Enable Internet Information Services.
2. Install URL Rewrite 2.0 from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
3. Install Application Request Routing 3.0 from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)
4. Open Internet Information Services Manager
5. Add Web Site. Set site name and physical path. On the bindings section, specify 26308 port (my personal convention: IIS Express port - 1). Leave host name blank.
6. Click on the newly created web site. On the right pane open "URL Rewrite"
7. On the Actions pane click on "Add Rule", Select "Reverse Proxy"
8. Write localhost:26309 on the text box "Enter the server name or the IP address..."
9. Click OK
10. Add an exception rule for TCP port 26308 to the Windows Firewall.

Now you need to modify you cordova app to make requests to the newly created web site on IIS. It needs to make requests to `http://192.168.8.162:26308` or `http://yourMachine.yourDomain.com:26308`

In this way you can debug your cordova app and the web api app at the same time, I mean you can add break points to both. 
It works for emulated devices as well as physical devices attached to USB. You will need a proper wifi accessible by your development machine and device.

Answer (score 3):

**2020 UPDATE**. What worked for me:

```
ionic cordova run android --no-native-run --livereload --external
```

Also adding this to `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
...
</platform>
```

Comment: This really helped me thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Issue :** have been also having the same issue and found out that was using `ionic cordova run android -livereload`  and when i normally run my app it was giving me this error:

`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
when i checked my config i find that  `-livereload` Flag added `src="http://localhost:8100"` to this

`<content original-src="index.html" src="http://localhost:8100" />`

instead of this :

`<content src="index.html" />`

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen due to couple of reasons.

Ensure that the URL you are trying to access is valid or not.

Then make sure you have CORS enabled in your backend application. To do this, use **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors** or if you are using OWIN then in startup.cs configuration, use  **app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll)** (this comes from **Microsoft.Owin.Cors**)

After you are done doing this, please go to your web.config and type in the following things:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This will solve the problem.