# ionic POST request error, net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

i have an ionic app and i'm trying to test it on my android device. the app works when testing it on the browser using 'ionic serve' but when i run 'ionic run android' the post request does not seem to hit the server. I'm getting an error

```
'POST http://localhost:3000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'
```

for the server i'm using nodejs and have access-control..

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
    'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.status(200).end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

i've also installed cordova whitelist plugin and the meta content-security-policy like so..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *    'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * data:;"/>
```

but i'm still getting the same error. 
i've also tried using my ip instead of localhost and got this error.

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.1.66:3000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

i've followed this thread..
[net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062125/neterr-connection-refused-ionic)
suggesting that i enable CORS by installing the microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors.. i followed this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and now i'm totally lost. please help, i've been on this for 3 days now.
i appreciate all your help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a CONNECTION_REFUSED when you try to connect to `localhost` from the device, which makes sense - as the server process is not running on the device - it is running on your machine.

The second example is *more* correct, in that from the device, you are trying to connect to your machine - but we see a *different* error: CONNECTION TIMEOUT

This one is actually due to your local firewall; you will by default allow connections to that port from within your local host - but we need to do some magic to allow packets from the world to talk to that service.

Are you running the server process on *nix? Or Windows?

For *nix

```
# Using firewalld (advanced wrapper around iptables)
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=tcp/3000 --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload

# Using bare iptables
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

For Windows

Open the Firewall configuration, and under Inbound Rules find the listing for the server process that you are running.

Double click the entry to open the properties window - in here click Allow the Connection, and Apply.

From the device

Try to again connect to the server process on your computer.